# PYTHONPATH for Textmate2?

Tags: python, textmate2

I can not make TextMate2 to get my PYTHONPATH.

Things I tried:

1. Put the PYTHONPATH in Environment.plist (and rebooted. This was the way TM1 got it fine.)
2. Create env. variable PYTHONPATH in my .bash_profile
3. Using the launchctl commands to make it known on an even lower level to OSX
4. Adding a TM_PYTHONPATH to the TM2 preferences env. variables

This is how I verify that the PYTHONPATH is still not the one it ought to be (as compared to in an iPython session):

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was like point 4, but slightly different:

set **PYTHONPATH**, not **TM_PYTHONPATH** as the environment variable in the TM2 preferences.
(Thanks to Rob McBroom who pointed that out on the mailing list.)